# Activation hot key shortcut recorder

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am developing Mac (10.10) app
I have to support a hot key activation in my app like below image extracted from evernote.
[image]

[image]

---

Most of the applications have same look and feel for recording hot key.(I personally checked 3-4 apps).
How do I do this ? Is there a reusable component available to record a key pressed event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try integrating this library:
https://github.com/Kentzo/ShortcutRecorder

I use it in my projects and it works very well